# Can't recreate a frontdoor private link after removing it

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door, azure-private-link

I create a front door origin using a bicep, and it creates a private link to my app service. Then I go to the application, and approve this private link in the UI. This works as expected.

If I remove the private link (in the app service UI), and run my creation bicep again it will not add the private link back.

How can I ensure the bicep adds the private link, even if it's has existed and was removed?

This is my bicep:

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: applicationName
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroup)
}

resource fdOrigin 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/originGroups/origins@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'fd-origin'
  parent: fdOriginGroup
  properties: {
    hostName: '${applicationName}.azurewebsites.net'
    httpPort: 80
    httpsPort: 443
    originHostHeader: '${applicationName}.azurewebsites.net'
    priority: 1
    weight: 1000
    sharedPrivateLinkResource: {
      groupId: 'sites'
      privateLinkLocation: 'EastUS2'
      requestMessage: 'Created by Deployment Pipeline'
      status: 'Approved'
      privateLink: {
        id: appService.id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to provide solutions on powershell?

Comment: yes. Please do.

Answer (score 0):

> If a single private endpoint gets created for all the different
> origins across different origin groups in the same Azure Front Door profile.

Therefore, Azure will check its databases to see if a private endpoint has been created for a given tuple `(resourceId, tenant, region, groupId)` for a given resource, in this case an app service. Azure generates a new private endpoint if the tuple changes, otherwise it does not.

As a result, Azure won't create a new private endpoint if you delete and recreate your app service, nor will it create a new private endpoint if you create a new origin with the same app service. Moreover, you won't see new connections to approve if this private endpoint's lifetime is now scoped to origin rather than the backend resource.

To resolve this issue to get a new private endpoint connection make sure you remove all origins and origin groups under your tenant with the same `PrivateLinkResourceId, GroupId, PrivateLinkLocation` in order to receive a new private endpoint connection when you create an origin with `PrivateLinkResourceId, GroupId, PrivateLinkLocation`. Azure will internally delete the private endpoint after deleting all origins and origin groups.

I create a front door origin and it creates a private link to my app service. Then I go to the application and approve this private link in the UI like below:

[image]

Now create a dummy origin group and add any origin to associate routes like below:

[image]

Updates an existing route with the specified route name:

```c
Update-AzFrontDoorCdnRoute -ResourceGroupName testps-rg-da16jm -ProfileName fdp-v542q6 -EndpointName end001 -Name route001 -EnabledState "Enabled"
```

Now delete the origin group(s) which has the same set of Private Link location, resource ID and group ID. Where the app service was added before.

In my case which I created *orgin2*-> unassociated and deleted like below:

[image]

To delete an AzureFrontDoor origin group under the profile

```
Remove-AzFrontDoorCdnOriginGroup -ResourceGroupName testps-rg-da16jm -ProfileName fdp-v542q6 -OriginGroupName org001
```

You need to delete the origin group where the app service was added before. And also delete any other origin groups containing an origin with the same set of Private Link location, resource ID and group ID. Once the origin groups are deleted, you can recreate the origin group with the newly created app service, and you will see new private endpoint connections to approve.

To create new origin group, make use of below code:

```c
# Define Health Probe and Load Balancing settings
$healthProbeSetting = New-AzFrontDoorCdnOriginGroupHealthProbeSettingObject -ProbeIntervalInSecond 1 -ProbePath "/" -ProbeProtocol "Https" -ProbeRequestType "GET"
$loadBalancingSetting = New-AzFrontDoorCdnOriginGroupLoadBalancingSettingObject -AdditionalLatencyInMillisecond 200 -SampleSize 5 -SuccessfulSamplesRequired 4

# Create an Azure Front Door CDN Origin Group
New-AzFrontDoorCdnOriginGroup -ResourceGroupName v-rukmini-mindtree -ProfileName rukfd -OriginGroupName org001 -LoadBalancingSetting $loadBalancingSetting -HealthProbeSetting $healthProbeSetting
```

Now my private link appears successfully like below:

[image]

**So generally, to get a private link you need to create a dummy origin group delete the origin group where the app service was added before, as well as any other origin groups with similar Private Link location, resource ID, and group ID. To delete an origin group, it must be unassociated from route.**

**Edit the Azure Front Door route to disassociate the origin group you want to delete. You can associate another existing origin group or create a new dummy origin group and add it to the route. once unassociated delete the origin group of app service. Now you can recreate the origin group with the newly created app service and enable private link. You will see new private endpoint connections that need approval within your app service.**

***Using CLI:***

To edit a route :  [az afd route update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/route?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-route-update)

To create a dummy origin group : [az afd origin-group create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cdn/new-azfrontdoorcdnorigingroup?view=azps-10.4.1)

To delete origin group: [az afd origin-group delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/origin-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-origin-group-delete)